# How to show $E[F_2(X_1)] + E[F_1(X_2)] = 1+ P\{X_1=X_2\}?$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$  Suppose, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent random variables with distribution function $F_1$ and $F_2$ respectively .

Show that $E[F_2(X_1)] + E[F_1(X_2)] = 1+ P\{X_1=X_2\}$

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$  Actually,I know a result that $E[F(X)]= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x} (P\{X=x\})^2$

But, I can't think how I can apply this result in this problem .The term $1$ at the right hand side appears by adding $1/2$ with itself .

How to work with $F_1(X_2)$ and $F_2(X_1)?$

A small hint will be a boon for me at this time, many many thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoting by $\mu_1$ the distribution of $X_1$ and $\mu_2$ that of $X_2$ we have
$$
\mathbb E[F_2(X_1)]=\int_{\mathbb R}F_2(x_1)\,\mu_1(dx_1)=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}1_{\{x_2\le x_1\}}\,\mu_1(dx_1)\,\mu_2(dx_2).
$$

We have a similar expression for $\mathbb E[F_1(X_2)]$. The desired equality is then just the observation that $1_{\{x_2\le x_1\}}+1_{\{x_1\le x_2\}}=1+1_{\{x_1=x_2\}}$.